# I think I didn't correctly install C/C++

Tags: c, eclipse-plugin

[image]

I'm unsure exactly what this means tried installing C plug in to eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Steps for installing C or C++ on eclipse are following.

1) Install MinGW GCC or Cygwin GCC.

2) Install Eclipse C/C++ Development Tool (CDT)

**you must have GCC to run C/C++ on your system**

Check the below given link for more details:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-do-I-set-up-C-Cplusplus-on-Eclipse-in-Windows